# Values of webform fields are showing as 'null' while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was trying to submit the below ASP Webform, and i entered values for all the four fields and clicked 'Submit'.

While debugging, it shows values of all the four fields as 'null'. Not sure what im missing. I have attached images of debugging and codes for your reference.

Webform code:

```html
<div style="margin-left:20px">
    <h6><a>Disposition Details:</a></h6>
<table id="myTable" runat="server" style="outline:thin solid">
  <tr>
    <th>Serial Numbers</th>
    <th>Disposition Result</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th>Note for Group</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" name="field1[]" /></td>
    <td><input runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" name="field2[]" /></td>    
    <td><textarea runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" name="field3[]"> 
   </textarea></td>
    <td><textarea runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" name="field4[]"> 
 </textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="AddRowButton_Click" />
 </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <label runat="server" id="lblMessage"></label>
    <label style="white-space:nowrap;margin-right:30px" runat="server" 
id="submitStatus"></label> 
</form>

<div class="form-group" style="display: ;justify-content: flex-end;">  
        <div class="form-group" style="display:flex ; justify-content: flex-end;">
           <input value="Cancel" style="width:250px;color:white;background-color:#6c757d;border-radius:5px;height:39px;border:none;margin-right: 10px;" runat="server" type="button" cssClass="btn" onserverclick ="btnCnl_Cancel" />               
            
           <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" Width="250px" ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnDis_submit" />
            
        </div>           
</div>
```

C# Function:

```
protected async void btnDis_submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var formData = new
            {
                correctiveActions = new List<string>(),
                dispositionDetails = new List<object>()
            };

            // Get the selected values of the corrective actions checkboxes and add them to the "correctiveActions" list
            foreach (DevExpress.Web.ListEditItem item in ASPxCheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    formData.correctiveActions.Add(item.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            // Get the values of the disposition details fields and add them to the "dispositionDetails" list
            foreach (HtmlTableRow row in myTable.Rows)
            {
                var field1Ctrl = row.FindControl("field1[]") as HtmlInputText;
                var field2Ctrl = row.FindControl("field2[]") as HtmlInputText;
                var field3Ctrl = row.FindControl("field3[]") as HtmlTextArea;
                var field4Ctrl = row.FindControl("field4[]") as HtmlTextArea;

                string field1 = field1Ctrl?.Value;
                string field2 = field2Ctrl?.Value;
                string field3 = field3Ctrl?.Value;
                string field4 = field4Ctrl?.Value;

                formData.dispositionDetails.Add(new
                {
                    field1 = field1,
                    field2 = field2,
                    field3 = field3,
                    field4 = field4
                });
            }

            string apiUrl2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl2"];
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData);

            // Post the form data to the API endpoint
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                string response = client.UploadString("https://itapps/nmrapi/api/NMRController/SendEmail", "POST", jsonData);
                if (response == "success")
                {
                    lblMessage.InnerText = "Form submitted successfully!";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.InnerText = "Form submission failed.";
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            submitStatus.InnerText = "Error submitting form data." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Below is the result of debugging. Im in learning phase of .NET and im not sure where it went wrong.

[image]

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: yes! My code is not finding the ID control for the four fields. That is clear and that is the reason for returning null i believe. Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: That is the problem. Your controls do not have an ID. It's not the same as `name`

Answer (score 0):

changed below code

```
var field1Ctrl = row.FindControl("field1[]") as HtmlInputText;
```

to

```
var field1Ctrl = row.FindControl("field1") as HtmlInputText;
```

and it now receiving values. Thank you

Comment: any particular reason why you not using asp.net controls here? It would save world poverty and time on your part.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. Can you please explain the asp.net controls part here.